# XPages - init a CSJS function with every partial refresh

Tags: xpages

I would like to inititiate a csjs function every time a partial refresh is triggered/completed in XPages.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the partial hijack code in combination with a dojo subscribe ? See http://dontpanic82.blogspot.fr/2010/01/xpages-hijackingpublishing-partial.html

Comment: You might also need this: https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=serialized-partial-refresh-calls-v1.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your partially refreshed element is a container, just place a script block inside this container and call your CSJS script.

Comment: i have many containers and not all partial refresh update all containers so that is not going to work if I want to keep my code in just 1 place. I tried the dojo subscribe but that seems not to work (any longer?) http://dontpanic82.blogspot.com/2013/03/fix-for-partial-refresh-on-dojo-tab.html